# HOW to select file according to intl setting

Tags: file, select, wix, wix3.5

i have the following requirement: i need to install some files just to some special intl version. how can i do this?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a condition on the component.  Take a look at the following link for potential properties to use.  I suspect you'll be interested in the SystemLanguageID property.   You might also want to set the Transitive flag con the components in case you think the user might ever chane their default language.  Repairing the MSI after such a change would cause some of your files to be removed and others installed to sync up to the new condition evaluations.

[Operating System Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#operating_system_properties)

[SystemLanguageID Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372056%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Using Transitive Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: but how to add the condition? like "loc.Language == 1033"?

Comment: loc.Language is only available during the build. During execution of the installer you should be able to use SystemLanguageID. You use a Condition element as a child of your Component element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Component Id ="main_test_file2" Guid="{914ED802-82E1-4296-85F2-4095DE0AAC1D}" KeyPath="yes">
            <Condition>"!(loc.Language)"="1033"</Condition>
            <File Id="file2" Source=".\Test1\Test1.txt"></File>
          </Component>
```

attach the code :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for installing files on specific environment you can go for [DotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/). In that you can specify the condition to launch the setup for certain environments.

While if you want to deploy certain files for an environment then you can use CustomAction and check the requirements and on the basis of that you can install the files.